# Use memory region as stack space?

Tags: c++, c, linux, memory, stack

In Linux is it possible to start a process (e.g. with `execve`) and make it use a particular memory region as stack space?

Background:

I have a C++ program and a fast allocator that gives me "fast memory". I can use it for objects that make use of the heap and create them in fast memory. Fine. But I also have a lot of variable living on the stack. How can I make them use the fast memory as well?

Idea: Implement a "program wrapper" that allocates fast memory and then starts the actual main program, passing a pointer to the fast memory and the program uses it as stack. Is that possible?

[Update]

The pthread setup seems to work.

Comment: I don't really think that your *fast* allocator can be any faster than stack allocation. In general, stack allocation takes a couple of instructions per function. Or do you mean that the memory is *faster* than the memory anywhere else in the system?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas the latter! Its the memory that's fast, not the allocator

Comment: What platform are you using where there are two different types of RAM?

Comment: How often do you want to transfer stack objects (not the memory referenced by them) to the GPU? Using that allocator speeds up transfers to the GPU, but will lock the page in memory, and that will have an impact on the rest of the system (the stack of your object can no longer be swapped out, for example) Are you sure you want to use this for *all* local variables?

Comment: I know. Its just an idea. The problem is i have lots of local vars to transfer. Speed is not the only benefit. You get async transfers as well. (That is what i am after.) Before i end up copying those into a contiguous buffer i find this idea here neat

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With pthreads, you could use a secondary thread for your program logic, and set *its* stack address using `pthread_attr_setstack()`:

```
NAME
       pthread_attr_setstack,  pthread_attr_getstack  -  set/get stack
       attributes in thread attributes object

SYNOPSIS
       #include <pthread.h>

       int pthread_attr_setstack(pthread_attr_t *attr,
                                 void *stackaddr, size_t stacksize);

DESCRIPTION
       The pthread_attr_setstack() function sets the stack address and
       stack  size attributes of the thread attributes object referred
       to by attr to the values specified in stackaddr and  stacksize,
       respectively.   These  attributes specify the location and size
       of the stack that should be used by a thread  that  is  created
       using the thread attributes object attr.

       stackaddr should point to the lowest addressable byte of a buf‐
       fer of stacksize bytes that was allocated by the  caller.   The
       pages  of  the  allocated  buffer  should  be both readable and
       writable.
```

What I don't follow is how you're expecting to get any performance improvements out of doing something like this (I assume the purpose of your "fast" memory is better performance).

Comment: Awesome! Not sure if it works in my case, will give it a try. Your question: The fast allocator is `cudaHostAlloc` returns page-locked memory that is used for accelerated memory transfers to GPUs. Thus, if this works, I can accelerate copies of stack variables!!

Comment: @Frank: Interesting. Let us know how it goes.